# Change PandasDF values for whole row if value is 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a (very) big pd.DataFrame which contains True/False or 1/0, I can change that if necessary for the working result.

If a value in a row is 1 I want the whole rest of the row to be filled with 1's

Input would look like this:

```
Index    Day1   Day2   Day3   Day4
  1       0      1      0      0
  2       1      1      0      0
  3       0      0      0      0
```

My desired goal is to look like this:

```
Index    Day1   Day2   Day3   Day4
  1       0      1      1      1
  2       1      1      1      1
  3       0      0      0      0
```

It is possible to iterate through all rows and change the values "manually" but I was wondering if there is a nicer solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), compare if greater like `0` and convert mask to `0,1` value by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df = df.cumsum(axis=1).gt(0).astype(int)
print (df)
       Day1  Day2  Day3  Day4
Index                        
1         0     1     1     1
2         1     1     1     1
3         0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number of columns is reasonably small, I would iterate over the columns:

```
for col in reversed(df.columns[1:-1]):
    df.loc[df[col]==1, col:] = 1
```

it gives as expected:

```
   Index  Day1  Day2  Day3  Day4
0      1     0     1     1     1
1      2     1     1     1     1
2      3     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have a large number of columns, thus jezraels answer is easier to apply for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas Dataframe .transform() method. Check for membership in the row and replace.

```
df.transform(lambda row: [1]*4 if 1 in row.values else row, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I used the solution of jezrael.